# Remove all matching nodes in a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

There are two things wrong with my script that i need help understanding.

The `if` statement looks for matching values in the original list. Then removes it.  This doesn't work for some reason. the `items.Remove(item)` doesn't actually remove the item.

The else statement works. But i have a feeling that i can do this all in one line.

Thoughts? If possible I would like to avoid making it a list. Its originally an `ObservableCollection`.

```
var items = TreeViewCollection.ToList();

if (items.Contains(SelectedTreeViewItem))
    items.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem);
else
    items.ForEach(e=>e.Nodes.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem));
```

UPDATE: Ive updated the code to make a little more sense.

My goal is to make this into one line.

```
if (TreeViewCollection.Contains(SelectedTreeViewItem))
    TreeViewCollection.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem);
else
    TreeViewCollection.ToList().ForEach(e=>e.Nodes.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem));
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The call to `items.Remove()` should remove the item just fine. But it removes it from the `items` list. Did you want it removed from the `TreeViewCollection` object instead? You need to provide a good [mcve] and explain precisely what that code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: did you debug through the code and make sure it goes inside of the `if`?

Comment: Yes i did debug the code to see if it got inside of the if and it did. I even debugged to code to see if it go inside of the else and it did.  The else works as expected but the if doesn't.

Comment: ToList is not needed . You can remove directly from TreevIewCollection

Comment: Observable Collection doesnt support ForEach.  Is there a work around?

Comment: this may help http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/remove-an-item-form-observable-collection-using-remove/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new list is counterproductive. `SelectedTreeViewItem` will be removed from list but not from original collection.

`ForEach` is not an extension method for IEnumerable, it is a common method of `List<T>` class. It returns `void`, so it can only be in the end of Linq methods chain. Using `foreach` makes code simpler and clearly states its intent:

```
bool del = TreeViewCollection.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem);
if (false == del)
    foreach(var t in TreeViewCollection)
        t.Nodes.Remove(SelectedTreeViewItem);
```